# Replacing static chart.js example with data from database

Tags: laravel, chart.js, adminlte

I have followed the tutorial on chart.js to create a static chart.  I am using Laravel and AdminLTE and can output my sql database results on the same view.  Can someone help me modify the static chart.js data to use the two records from the database.

I tried creating a foreloop and array but no luck.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <br />
        <h3 aligm="center">Artist Data</h3>
        <br />
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>PlayerID</th>
                <th>Score<th>
            </tr> 
            @foreach($artist as $row)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$row['playerid']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['score']}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </table> 
    </div>
</div>              

<h1>Chart</h1>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['John', 'Fred'],
                    datasets: [{
                    label: 'score',
                    data: [20, 19],
                    backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

The chart shows the results from the sql database.  The foreach ($artist as $row) is outputting a table so I know the database is connected.